# Statically link firebird driver for dbexpress

Tags: delphi, firebird, drive, dbexpress

Is it possible to deploy zero-dll executable that connects to Firebird using dbExprss? If so, how?

> Cause I've tried to include
>   DBXFirebird but the executable always
>   needs dbxfb.dll.

Thank you all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Up to Delphi 2006, you can link the dbExpress driver DLLs into your application by including the appropriate unit.

[Since Delphi 2007](http://www.prototypical.co.uk/pdf/ddbx4.pdf), this is no longer the case, and you have to ship the driver DLL.

Comment: Thanks Bruce, the PDF was really helpful.